# Json result to table

Tags: html, json, asp.net-mvc

I Would like when doing the search the results to be inputed to a table my results are being taken from my web service table

```
function DoSearch() {
                $("#resultsDiv").html("");
                var key = { "key": $("#SearchString").val() };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "/Stadium.asmx/GetStadiumByName",
                    data: JSON.stringify(key),
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (result, textStatus) {
                        if (textStatus == "success") {
                            for (var i = 0; i < result.d.length; i++) {
                                $("#resultsDiv").html($("#resultsDiv").html() + result.d[i] + "<br/>");
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (result, status, error) {
                        $("#resultsDiv").html("Error: " + error + " <br/>")
                    }
                });
            }
```

Below is my webservice file this gets all the information im looking for in my search.

```
[WebMethod]
        public object[] GetStadiumByName(string key)
        {
            List<object> stadiums = new List<object>();

            if (key != "")
            {
                 foreach(var Name in db.Stadiums



                    .Where(a => a.Name.Contains(key))
                    .ToList())
                {
                    stadiums.Add(Name.Name);
                    stadiums.Add(Name.Location);
                    stadiums.Add(Name.Team);
                    stadiums.Add(Name.Capacity);



                }
            }
            return stadiums.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

The search returns the following I want to put that information in a table[image]

Comment: What is your question and what problems are you having

Comment: I want my Json result to print to a html table

Comment: Great. What problems are you having?

Comment: i can't seem to figure out how to do it

Comment: You should take a look at [Jquery Data table](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html) which supports multiple data sources types including jason and generates HTML table.

Comment: my search is being pulled from a web service file therefore i dont know how to call the result to a table

Comment: `success: function (result, textStatus)` in the body of this callback function you just need provide the `result` to datatable once you have defined the Html table structure. You seem to be really new with web.

Comment: iv'e already tried that didn't work

Comment: Have you defined the datatable and added proper reference to the library.  Press `F12` in your browser go to console windows look for errors, fix them if any.

Comment: please review my post I have made what im trying to do more clear sorry for the confusion